# highcharter heatmap not following hc_coloraxis when there's negative values

Tags: r, highcharts

Hi.

I am trying to set colors from -1 to 1 as designed in the stops argument of hc_colorAxis. This works fine if there are no negative values in the correlation matrix. However, when there are negative values it resets to these default colors of blue, white, and red.

Here is the code with data:

```
library(BatchGetSymbols)
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)

t1 = BatchGetSymbols(c("MSFT", "SPY", "SH"))[[2]]
t2 = t1[,c("ticker", "ref.date", "ret.adjusted.prices")]
t3 = na.omit(pivot_wider(t2, names_from = ticker, values_from = "ret.adjusted.prices"))
t4 = cor(t3[,2:4])

hchart(type = "heatmap", t4) %>%
  hc_legend(layout = "vertical", verticalAlign = "middle", align = "right") %>%
  hc_colorAxis(min = -1, max = 1, stops = color_stops(3, c("#d51f3a", "#FFFFFF", "#5daa45")))
```

Here is what I am getting:
[image]

This is what I am trying to get (replace "SH" in t1 for "AAPL"):

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about looping through all points, finding ones that have negative colorValue and then changing their color?

Like this demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7p0ufcma

Then you could use the Highcharts JS API. You can see a handy article on how to do it here:
https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/working-with-highcharts-javascript-syntax-in-r/?fbclid=IwAR3UzztbrY4rdCbOw1W7DmSq4mWJswJZxIw-xOqGbjIRExj-gsuVEO2zM00

```
  chart.series[0].data.forEach(point => {
    if (point.colorValue < 0) {
      point.update({
        color: 'red'
      });
    }
  })
```